# How to: Interact with a slider using Playwright

Tags: playwright, uislider, browser-automation, playwright-typescript

**What I expected**
I am attempting to interact with a slider ui element on my angular based webpage. The code shown below is not interacting with the elements in question anymore. It was at one point..

**More Info**

Reading on the "white-space" issue mentioned, this is called "view-trailing". I am not 100% sure this relates to the issue.

**What I have tried**

I am having issues interacting with a slider on a webpage built with angular. Through my current solution

```
 async slideToAgree() {
    const { page } = this

    const {
      width: sw,
      height: sh,
      x: sx,
      y: sy
    } = await (await page.$('.slider-controller')).boundingBox();

    const { width: tw, x: tx } = await (
      await page.$('.slider-container')
    ).boundingBox();

    await page.mouse.move(sx + sw / 2, sy + sh / 2);
    await page.mouse.down();
    await page.mouse.move(tx + tw, sy + sh / 2, { steps: 10 });

  }
}
```

**What actually happened / result**

Playwright is clicking on the top right of the screen, outside of the webpage in this strange "extra white space".. making me think the bounding box for the element is broken / not attached to the DOM?

Can someone please provide an updated implementation of "Click and drag" or "interacting with a slider"? Nothing I have ran into so far has worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe it will solve your problem using the width of the slider instead of the relative to viewport position of the box? I don't know how your slider looks like, so I tested against a generic slider written in Angular and it seems to [drag](https://playwright.dev/docs/input#dragging-manually) the slider as intended:

```js
import {test} from '@playwright/test'

test('Move slider', async ({ page, context }) => {

    await page.goto('https://material.angular.io/components/slider/examples')
    const sliderTrack = await page.locator('.mdc-slider__track').first()
    const sliderOffsetWidth = await sliderTrack.evaluate(el => {
        return el.getBoundingClientRect().width
    })

    // Using the hover method to place the mouse cursor then moving it to the right
    await sliderTrack.hover({ force: true, position: { x: 0, y: 0 } })
    await page.mouse.down()
    await sliderTrack.hover({ force: true, position: { x: sliderOffsetWidth, y: 0 } })
    await page.mouse.up()

})
```

Comment: Thank you for the review, this was close but not interacting with the element. The solution was to add a view weird waits in to allow the application css to adjust for the viewport.

Enjoy the bounty award!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the great answer of @candre
if you need to click on the slider use the `.click()` method with the same parameters such as the `hover()`:

```
await sliderTrack.click({ force: true, position: { x: (sliderOffsetWidth / 3), y: 0 } });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems to consider:

1. while moving a thumb you should respect the slider step size in pixels (my code deals with it by gradually increasing the shift until value is changed)
2. slider might be in position 3 while you're looking for 2 (must scan entire values range)

```js
import { type Locator, type Page, test } from '@playwright/test';

test('Any slider move', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://material.angular.io/components/slider/examples');

  const slider = page.locator('.mat-mdc-slider').first();
  const sliderThumb = slider.locator('.mdc-slider__thumb').first();
  const value = slider.locator('.mdc-slider__input').first();

  await slideTo(
    page,
    sliderThumb,
    async () => {
      const strV = await value.getAttribute('aria-valuetext');
      if (strV == null) {
        throw new Error("Can't read the slider value");
      }
      return parseInt(strV, 10);
    },
    (v) => v === 10,
  );
});

async function slideTo(
  page: Page,
  sliderThumb: Locator,
  value: () => Promise<number>,
  done: (v: number) => boolean,
) {
  await sliderThumb.waitFor({
    timeout: 500,
  });

  let thumbMoveBy = 2;
  let stepSizeOk = false;

  const hoverTimeout = 1000;

  await sliderThumb.hover({ force: true, timeout: hoverTimeout });
  await page.mouse.down();
  await sliderThumb.hover({ force: true, position: { x: -1000, y: 0 }, timeout: hoverTimeout });
  await page.mouse.up();

  let lastValue = await value();

  while (!done(lastValue)) {
    await sliderThumb.hover({ force: true, timeout: hoverTimeout });
    await page.mouse.down();
    await sliderThumb.hover({
      force: true,
      position: { x: thumbMoveBy, y: 0 },
      timeout: hoverTimeout,
    });
    await page.mouse.up();
    await page.waitForTimeout(10);
    const newValue = await value();
    if (newValue === lastValue) {
      if (stepSizeOk) {
        throw new Error(`Slider stop at ${lastValue}, value was not found`);
      }
      thumbMoveBy += 2;
    } else {
      lastValue = newValue;
      stepSizeOk = true;
    }
  }
}
```